# Trouble downloading Python modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pygame

I was making a Tetris game and at the top of the Python code, I put in `import pygame`, since that was the thing I was thinking of doing and the thing I thought I could only do. My game was complete, the terminal was open, and I ran the code. The terminal gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[removed for safety]", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

So I tried pip installing it with the command `pip install pygame`, but it just returns a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named 'typing'
```

I was using
VSCode, with Python version 3.10.5, 64-bit.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `typing` was added in 3.5.

Comment: @MattDMo I added that information to the original question, this will probably help more.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Describe exactly what you're doing, and include the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: From the `pip` traceback, you are using Python 3.4, hence the `typing` error. This is probably a PATH issue. Check it out and clean out references to Python 3.4, making sure only Python 3.10 is there.

Comment: @MattDMo I am new to programming and coding, so I don't know EXACTLY how to do that.

Comment: I'm sure you're able to find out how to add something to PATH using Google, well, instead of adding, remove something from it, should be really simple actually, just follow the steps to find the part where you get to the place where you can configure PATH, the rest should be easy

Comment: @MattDMo so i remove stuff like C:\Python34 and C:\Python34\Scripts?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Make sure your Python 3.10 entries are at the top, so they'll be scanned first.

Comment: I don't see anything related to 3.10. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can uninstall `python 3.4` from your system, with [this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) then you can reinstall python from from the [python.org](https://python.org/downloads/windows/) website. Then hopefully `pip install pygame` would work. Or, if pygame is installed run `pip uninstall pygame` then `pip install pygame`

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I ran pip install pygame. By the way, besides being for different operating systems, is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

> File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main

**Python34** is mentioned in the error code, which indicates that the terminal runtime retrieves **python3.4** instead of **3.10** you mentioned.

This indicates that there are **multiple versions of Python** in your environment.

You can manually select the Python interpreter by using shortcut **"ctrl+shift+P"** and typing "**python: select interpreter**" or click this icon to change the interpreter:

[image]

After choosing the correct interpreter, you can use command `pip install pygame` to install python package at the correct python-lib.